# Accessing JSON Keys with Twig

Tags: html, json, twig

Currently using OctoberCMS and Twig to get dynamic data and translations on the front end that come from JSON files. For example:

```
<div class="wrapper items">
  <div class="items">
    {% for suggestion in 'form.suggestions'|trans %}
    <div class="item" data-subject="{{ suggestion(KEYS) }}">
      {{ suggestion}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
"form":{
   "suggestions": {
      "suggestion1": "This is suggestion 1",
      "suggestion2": "This is suggestion 2",
      "suggestion3": "This is suggestion 3",
      "suggestion4": "This is suggestion 4",
      "suggestion5": "This is suggestion 5",
      "suggestion6": "This is suggestion 6",
      "suggestion7": "This is suggestion 7",
      "suggestion8": "This is suggestion 8",
      "suggestion9": "This is suggestion 9",
      "suggestion10": "This is suggestion 10",
      "suggestion11": "This is suggestion 11",
      "suggestion12": "This is suggestion 12",
      "suggestion13": "This is suggestion 13",
      "suggestion14": "This is suggestion 14",
      "suggestion15": "This is suggestion 15"
    },
}
```

I've currently got a for each loop and need both the keys and values from the JSON file. At the moment, I can only access the value but not the keys, and I can't seem to figure out how to access them. Is this possible at all with Twig and if it is, how could I get this to work?

Comment: `{% for key, value in array %}...{% endfor %}`

Comment: this will help you https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/twig/objects-and-arrays

Comment: @DarkBee that's a great suggestion, but I should have mentioned this in the OP. I tried that earlier and only got "item" as a result.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing `in 'form.suggestions'|trans` though? ([demo](https://twigfiddle.com/9f03vq))

Comment: @DarkBee like I mentioned, it's a translation filter that we're using to include the page contents dynamically based on the user's locale.

Comment: What does `{{ dump('form.suggestions'|trans) }}` output then

Comment: Just wanted to say,  I changed "key" to something else and it seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @DarkBee, I simply changed the word "key" for "subject" instead, and this works fine. No idea why "key" didn't work the same way, but this seemed to have solved the issue for me. Appreciate the assistance!